# Python popen sysargv

Tags: python, popen

I want to open a script with popen, with a sysargv argument like this:

```
import subprocess

Script = '/home/Network_Monitor_Device/Scripts/Traceroute.py 192.168.76.1'

p = subprocess.Popen(['python','-u',Script], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

out = p.stdout.readline()

print out
```

**Traceroute.py**

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.check_output("traceroute " + str(sys.argv[1]), shell=True)
```

I'm getting this error:

> python: can't open file
>   '/home/Network_Monitor_Device/Scripts/Traceroute.py 192.168.76.1':
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expecting a list. Try:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python','-u', '/home/Network_Monitor_Device/Scripts/Traceroute.py', '192.168.76.1'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: When I try that, I'm getting this error: `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`

Comment: That did it! Thanks!